# Is it possible to send notifcation FROM a Tkinter Pc software (program that captures snapshots) TO a seperate kivymd Mobile Software using Firebase

Tags: python, firebase, tkinter, push-notification, kivymd

I'm trying to create a notification function that shows up in the banner notification to the separate apps that I'm trying to develop using Firebase database. The first .Py file uses a Tkinter Module and Open Cv that will capture an image and the second .Py file which uses a KivyMd Module that will receive the notification.

For now I've created a Login, signup and a main frame and I'm still searching if its possible to accomplish this.